# Join Parts of the Newest Item in Another Table using a View

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating a custom forum.  My forum needs to be able to display the number of threads in the forum, a link to the thread with the most recent post, as well as a link to the poster's profile.  To this, I need the number of threads in each forum as well as the most recent post.  So I know what I need.  The problem?  I'm far from an expert in anything SQL beyond "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = value"

Here is my table, tbl_Forums, schema:

```
ForumID        INT            IDENTITY(1,1)
Name           NVARCHAR(128)  NOT NULL
```

And here is my tbl_Forum_Threads schema:

```
ThreadID       INT            IDENTITY(1,1)
ForumID        INT            NOT NULL
UserID         INT            NOT NULL
Name           NVARCHAR(128)  NOT NULL
```

And, finally, my tbl_Forum_Posts schema:

```
PostID         INT            IDENTITY(1,1)
ThreadID       INT            NOT NULL
UserID         INT            NOT NULL
Body           NVARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL
PostTime       DATETIME       NOT NULL
```

So, with this in mind, here is the view I've been working on that does not work at all, as in, Visual Studio can't even successfully execute this query (I think it would be called a query) successfully:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_ForumsAndStats] AS
SELECT 
    f.*,
    COUNT(t.ThreadID) AS NumberOfThreads,
    p.PostID AS MostRecentPostID,
    p.ThreadID AS MostRecentPostThreadID,
    p.UserID AS MostRecentPostUserID
FROM tbl_Forums f
JOIN tbl_Forum_Threads t ON t.ForumID = f.ForumID
RIGHT JOIN tbl_Forum_Posts p ON p.ThreadID IN (SELECT t.ThreadID) AND p.PostID = (SELECT MAX(p.PostID))
```

Comment: You need to explain what "does not work" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues exist:

1. COUNT is an aggregate function which requires a GROUP BY in your select clause
2. The join to tbl_Forum_Posts is flawed (as in syntactically incorrect). Conceptually you need to break that join into 2 parts: Find the MAX(PostID) per Forum, then join back to the post table again to get more detailed info about that max post id

Something like:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_ForumsAndStats] AS
SELECT 
    f.*,
    COUNT(t.ThreadID) AS NumberOfThreads,
    p.PostID AS MostRecentPostID,
    p.ThreadID AS MostRecentPostThreadID,
    p.UserID AS MostRecentPostUserID
FROM tbl_Forums f
JOIN tbl_Forum_Threads t ON t.ForumID = f.ForumID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT t.ForumID, MAX(p.PostID) as MaxPostID 
           FROM tbl_Forum_Posts p
           JOIN tbl_Forum_Threads t ON p.ThreadID = t.ThreadID
           GROUP BY t.ForumID
          ) as MostRecentPost ON MostRecentPost.ForumID = f.ForumID
LEFT JOIN tbl_Forum_Posts p ON MostRecentPost.MaxPostID = p.PostID
GROUP BY f.ForumID, F.Name, p.PostID, p.ThreadID, p.UserID
```

I don't have a Sql Server in front of me, but that should be pretty close.

Also, I switched the Right Join to a Left Join: I assume your intent is to show Forums even if they have no Posts? (The Right join would have shown Posts even if they have no forums, which if you have foreign keys configured would be impossible).

Comment: The view was able to be put into the database, but when I view it's results, nothing comes up.  I should note that there is one row in the tbl_Forums table and nothing at all in either the tbl_Forum_Threads or tbl_Forum_Posts tables.

Comment: In that case, switch the Join to the tbl_Forums_Threads table to a LEFT JOIN.